# find the index of a letter in a string in python

Tags: string, python-2.7

I tried to print the index of every `i` in the word `Mississippi`. I've got the result but the print statement is repeating 3 times. This is the code

```
s="Mississippi"
start=0
while start<len(s):  
     print "the index of i is: ", s.find('i',start,len(s))
     start=start+1
```

Comment: First, not 3 times, but 10 times. Second: you call `print` in every `while`-iteration which means `len(s)` times. What do you expect?

Answer (score 2):

If you use [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) then you iterate through the string, looking at each letter and `idx` is counting upwards as you go.

```
for idx, letter in enumerate(s):
    if letter == "i":
        print "the index of i is: ", idx
```

Answer (score 1):

do you want to print the indexes as a list? try this:

```
l = []
for index, char in enumerate('mississippi'):
    if char == 'i':
        l.append(index)
print "the index of i is: ", l
```

the result will be:

> the index of i is:  [1, 4, 7, 10]

Answer (score 0):

Because of the while loop, you print the last found position of "i" in each run.

I would prefer a for loop over the string:

```
s="Misssssissippi"
start=0
character="i"

for i in s:
        if (i == character):
                print "the index of i is: ", start
        start=start+1
```

Comment: It's wasteful. You can set `start` to the next position after a found element and spare a lot of iterations.

Comment: the for loop is called len(s) times... no chance of saving iterations. same solution as mentioned by Joshua, but I upvoted the "enumerate"-solution, it's quite sexy!

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
s="Wisconsin"
for c in re.finditer('i',s):
    print c.start(0)
```

Comment: This only lucks itself into working because Mississippi ends in i. Try it with "Wisconsin" and you've got yourself an infinite loop.

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out. It never occurred to me. I have updated my answer.